# Probability that the a square-free number is divisible by a given prime number $p.$

Tags: probability, number-theory, divisibility

Probability that the a square-free number $n$ is divisible by a given prime number $p$ is $1/(p+1).$

I know that $n$ is square-free and number of square-free integers up-to $x$ is 
$$ \approx  x \prod_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) $$
Somehow I need to modify this to count the number that are divisible by $p.$

Comment: If you are looking for an approximation (as the notation suggests), we should multiply the number of square-free numbers "up-to $x$" by the probability that such numbers are "divisible by a given prime number" $p$.  Note that the use of $p$ as an index in counting the square-free numbers is distinct from the use of $p$ as a specified prime number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Outline:* Let $F(t)$ be the number of square-free numbers $\le t$. For large $t$, this is "approximately" $\frac{6}{\pi^2} t$.

We use an Inclusion/Exclusion argument. A first step to an answer is that the number of square-free numbers $\le x$ that are multiples of $p$ is approximately  $F(x/p)$. For multiplying a square-free number $\le x/p$ by $p$ yields (for sure) a multiple of $p$ that is $\le x$. It also yields a number which is "usually" square-free. The only perfect square that could possibly divide $py$, where $y\le x/p$ and $y$ is square-free is $p^2$.

Thus $F(x/p)$ overcounts our set of multiples of $p$ that are $\le x$ and square-free. To correct, we  must subtract approximately $F(x/p^2)$, which (almost) counts the number of numbers $\le x$ that are divisible by $p^2$   but are otherwise square-free.

We have subtracted too much, for we have subtracted one too many tines the numbers $\le x$ that are divisible by $p^3$ but are otherwise square-free. So we need to add back approximately $F(x/p^3)$, and so on.

The sum of the infinite geometric series $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}-\frac{1}{p^4}+\cdots$ is $\frac{1}{p}\cdot \frac{1}{1-(-1/p)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. However I am a bit confused at some points. I am confused about the part form "However this over counts for it counts the square-free numbers $\le x/p$ that are divisible by $p$, and multiplying by $p$ gives us a number that is almost square-free, apart from the unfortunate fact that it is divisible by $p^2$" You started to count numbers that are not divisible by $p$ then form there how its counting the square-free numbers $\le x/p$ that are divisible by $p$,??

Comment: I was trying to use informal language. Will modify the third paragraph to be somewhat less informal.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really good argument, however I am still in doubt but I will try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome Without Inclusion/Exclusion, we find that the ratio for large $x$ is less than $1/p$, but probably  not much less. With Inclusion/Exclusion we get an exact asymptotic answer.

Comment: This was actually a modified version of another question where I was supposed to find the probability that discriminant of a quadratic field is divisible by $p.$ I did some computations and realized that these two things are same for odd primes and probability is $1/(p+).$